# Auto Increment ID's of 4 digit

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

I am creating auto **increment customer id** to store in the database in the **4 digit .**

> 1. If i use only numbers then it is simple , but i have only **9999 users only**.Then in last it will be **10^4** which is equals to
>      **10000** **customer**.
> 2. If i also include letters , which is **26 letters** .Then in last it will be **36^4** which is equals to **1679616 customer**

**And using letters and numbers it be fine to store 1.5 million IDS for customer.**

Here is the idea how its work .....

> 0001
>
> 0002
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .   0009
>
> 000a
>
> 000b
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> 000z
>
> 0010
>
> 0011
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> 0019
>
> 001a
>
> 001b
>
> .
>
> .
>
> 001z
>
> 0020
>
> .
>
> aaa9    .
>
> aaaz
>
> aab0
>
> .
>
> .
>
> And last is zzzz

I created this code in android and java ........

```
void increment() {
        chars = mIds.getText().toString().toCharArray();
        String value = "" + getId(chars[3], 3);
        data = chars[0] + "" + chars[1] + "" + chars[2]  + "" + value + "";
        mIds.setText(data + " ");
    }

    private String getId(char aChar, int i) {
        if (Character.getNumericValue(aChar) == 9)
            return 'a' + "";
        else if (aChar == 'z') {
            i = i - 1;
            chars[i] = getId(chars[i], i).charAt(0);
            return '0' + "";
        } else {
            int num = (int) aChar;
            aChar = (char) (++num);
            return aChar + "";
        }
    }
```

**Looking for any algorithm or any codes which help me .....**

**If it really helpful if solution is get in `MySQL` or `PHP`.....**

**Thank all guys....**

Comment: just use INT 11 ?

Comment: how it will include letters in id ??

Comment: You're making this much more complicated than it needs to be

Comment: Indeed you should use a Unsigned INT so it can hold 4294967295 id's or Unsigned BIGINT so it can hold 18446744073709551615 id's

Comment: we have to assign per customer id so he can be remember the 4 digit IDS.

Comment: https://medium.com/@anujguptawork/how-to-create-your-own-android-library-and-publish-it-750e0f7481bf

Answer (score 1):

Make id as `varchar` and use php to make id like this

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<10+27;$i++){
  $number = base_convert($i,10,10+26);//here 26 is for a-z
  $number = str_pad($number, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  echo " ".$number;
}
?>
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/854013

I hope you can get `last inserted id` and then increment `id` by 1 as in loop above to insert new record.

output of above php code is :

> 0000 0001 0002 0003 0004 0005 0006 0007 0008 0009 000a 000b 000c 000d
>   000e 000f 000g 000h 000i 000j 000k 000l 000m 000n 000o 000p 000q 000r
>   000s 000t 000u 000v 000w 000x 000y 000z 0010